# Android MediaPlayer тормозит в Android L

Tags: android, mediaplayer

В Своем приложении, я использую MediaPlayer для воспроизведения потокового видео.

На девайсах с ОС ниже чем Android 5, видео показывается хорошо.

На девайсах с ОС Android 5 ужастно тормозит.

Кто то сталкивался с подобной проблемой, и ее решением?

Answer (score 1):

Пока что решил свою проблему использованием [ExoPlayer](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html) , но все же хотелось бы иметь возможность работать и со стандартным.
Так что вопрос все еще актуальный.

Comment: Если позволил себе переход на ExoPayer, то значит минималкой андроид поставил 16 уровень. Там все можно написать своими руками - эхо это надстройка над доступным инструментарием. А проблем со съехавшим контролом не возникало?